# forcehybrid create error

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, salesforce-sdk-android, cordova

friends!
I am going throuh the trail "Develop with Mobile SDK".

I installed Android Studio and a bunch of Android SDKs:
[image]

I have set ANDROID_HOME to `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.
While running `forcehybrid create` command i get an error:

[image]

It's worth mentioning that `tools` folder does not exist in `..\Android\Sdk` on my computer so it sounds pretty obvious that I indeed did not install Android Sdk properly...

I am stuck with it and I cannot find any information. Please help me out, any help is appreciated.